# intellij scala: Error: Could not find or load main class

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, apache-spark-sql

i have a R&D project that read data from oracle then write to spark standalone cluster by using scala & intellij

this is my build.sbt with library Dependencies

```
name := "DB_Oracle_V07"
version := "0.1"
scalaVersion := "2.11.12"
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-core
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "2.2.0"
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-sql
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "2.4.0"
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-hive
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-hive" % "2.4.0"
```

my project main class without any spark syntax

```
package com.xxxx.spark

import java.io.FileWriter
import java.sql.{Connection, DriverManager}
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat
import java.util.Calendar

import scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer

object query01 {

  var dateStart = ""
  case class DF_LOT_INFO(LOT_NUMBER: String, MACHINE: String, FACILITY: String, LOT_TYPE: String, REC_DATE: String, FILE_NAME: String)

  def main(args:Array[String]): Unit = {

    val cal = Calendar.getInstance
    cal.add(Calendar.DATE, 1)
    val date = cal.getTime
    val format1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss")
    dateStart = format1.format(date)

    print_log("start")

    val url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@TMDT1PEN.XXXX.XXXX.COM:1521:TMDT1"

    //val driver = "oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"
    val driver = "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"

    val username = "TMDB_XXXX"

    val password = "XXXXXXXX"

    val connection:Connection = null

    val result = ArrayBuffer[String]()

    try{

      print_log("Class.forName start")

      val app_dir = System.getProperty("user.dir")
      print_log("current dir: " + app_dir)
      val java_class_path = System.getProperty("java.class.path")
      print_log("java_class_path: " + java_class_path)

      Class.forName(driver)

      var testing = Class.forName(driver)


      print_log("Class.forName end")

      //DriverManager.registerDriver(new oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver)

      val connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password)


      val statement = connection.createStatement

      val rs = statement.executeQuery("select * from tester")

      var i = 1
      while(rs.next){
        val item = rs.getString("tester_name")
        println("data:" + item)
        print_log("data:" + item)
        result.append(item)
        i = i + 1
      }

      values('aaaaa','bbbbb',sysdate)")

    }
    catch{
      //case unknown => println("Got this unknown exception: " + unknown)
      case unknown => print_error_log("Unknown exception: " + unknown)
    }
    finally{

    }
    print_log("end")

  }

  def print_log(msg:String): Unit = {
    val fw = new FileWriter(dateStart + "_log.txt", true)
    try {
      fw.write("\n" + msg)
    }
    finally fw.close()
  }

  def print_error_log(msg:String): Unit = {
    val fw = new FileWriter(dateStart + "_error_log.txt", true)
    try {
      fw.write("\n" + msg)
    }
    finally fw.close()
  }

}
```

i build artifact as usual & added ojdbc6.jar in my proect .jar as my oracle library

[ojdbc6.jar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/smMBE.png)

but i fail to execute my project jar file and getting below error

```
Error: Could not find or load main class com.xxxx.spark.query01
```

blindly i removed all spark extracted jar files in my project .jar
or create a new project without any library Dependencies in build.sbt, 
then i able to execute my project .jar without error.

With above blind test i sure that the error is caused by spark library,
Any expert can advise me how to solve this error? Thanks for all :)

Comment: Could you give more details about your build process? How do you build jar file and do you run it?

Comment: >step 1, add 3 spark libraryDependencies in build.sbt
>step 2, coding on main class (object query01)
>step 3, debug 'query01.main', (complete without error) https://ibb.co/xC4xYzG
>step 4, C:\ojdbc.jar library (method: Extracted Directory) https://ibb.co/cbQLqNj
>step 5, Build Artifact
>step 6, run my project .jar with command prompt: Java -jar DB_Oracle_V07.jar C:\\Users\\S4003\\Desktop\\spark\\result
>step 7, Error: Could not find or load main class com.xxxx.spark.query01

Comment: If you go inside the built jar file, can you see the main class?

Comment: yes the main class is exist as print screen show https://ibb.co/j64LvGD

Comment: Do you get the same issue if you build artifact from command line, outside IDE?

Comment: As previous comment suggest, I would recommend alternative way to make this via sbt plugins. I did similar thing for Spark job using sbt-assembly. It has good notes for Spark case, when it comes to provided dependencies. So, first you could try to build your jar via SBT and see wether it works: https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly#excluding-jars-and-files